# Work done by a force Field

Tags: integration, physics

Homework for Calc III includes a problem about computing the work done by a force field (defined by a specific vector equation) on a moving particle.  I was attempting to compute this using the equation
$$ \int_a^b {\textbf{F}(\textbf{r}(t)) \bullet \textbf{r}'(t) \space \mathrm{d}}t$$ defined by the following vectors:
$$ \textbf{F}  (x,y) = xy\textbf{i}+3y^2\textbf{j} \space \mathrm{and} \space \textbf{r}(t)=11t^4\textbf{i}+t^3\textbf{j} \space\mathrm{for}\space 0 \le t \le 1$$

Alas, I computed $\textbf{r}'(t)=44t^3\textbf{i}+3t^2\textbf{j}$, which is never going to produce the answer of 45 that the book gives, unless I am doing something very very wrong..

Would someone be so kind as to resolve this for me?

Thanks!

**Edit**: *Wow*, when integrating, I forgot to multiply by $1\over n$ as in $\int x^n \space \mathrm{d}$.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: what are the values for $a$ and $b$?

Comment: And $f$ and $F$ are meant to be the same, right?

Comment: Right, good points guys, lemme fix that.... a little trouble with latex made me slip my details..

Comment: You are doing something wrong in your computation. The answer is 45.

Comment: Your approach is correct, it will lead to the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct, it will lead to the right answer.

\begin{align}
\textbf{F}(x,y) &= (xy,3y^2)\\
\textbf{r}(t) &= (11t^4, t^3)\\
\textbf{r}'(t) &= (44t^3, 3t^2)\\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \textbf{F}(\textbf{r}(t))\cdot\textbf{r}'(t)dt &= \int_0^1 (11t^4* t^3,3t^6)\cdot (44t^3, 3t^2)dt
\\
&= \int_0^1 484t^{10} + 9t^8dt
\\
&=\left.44t^{11} + t^9\right |_0^1
\\
&=45
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$r(t) = (11 t^4, t^3)$. $r'(t) = (44 t^3, 3 t^2)$. $f(r(t)) = (11 t^7, 3 t^6)$. $\langle f(r(t)), r'(t) \rangle = 484 t^{10} + 9 t^8$. Integrating the latter over $[0,1]$ gives $45$.